# Condition for a set to be a complete orthonormal base of Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

In a lecture of Nuclear Physics in which my professor was reviewing some result of functional analysis he said that a condition which can be used to tell if a orthonormal set is complete is:

$$
\sum_n W_n^*(\xi')W_n(\xi) = \delta(\xi'-\xi) 
$$

I can't find references for this equation, is a sufficient or a necessary condition? How can it be proven?

EDIT:
In the same lecture he said that the coefficient $a_n$ of the expansion of a function $f(\xi)$ in order to obtain:
$$
f(\xi) = \sum_n a_n W_n(\xi)
$$

can be calculated by the formula:
$$
a_n = \int W_n^* f W_n d\xi 
$$

But if i remember correctly my (too brief) course of introduction to functional analysis the teacher tell me that $a_n$ is given by the inner product and so the coefficient should be calculated by:
$$
a_n = \int f^* W_n d\xi 
$$

Which one is correct? What is the difference?

Comment: $a_n = \int f W_n^*d \xi$ is correct. That's how $f \sim \sum_{n} a_n W_n(x)= \sum_{n}\int f(\xi)W_n^*(\xi)d\xi W_n(x) "=" \int f(\xi) \sum_n W_n^*(\xi)W_n(x) d\xi$ focuses attention on $\sum_n W_n(x)W_n^*(\xi)$.

Comment: I have checked, and I mistyped in coping from the blackboard, obviously is like you said. What about the first question? I'm pretty sure that equation is correct but I've never seen it before

Comment: Delta functions in this context are not easily made rigorous. But the $L^2$ expansion $f(\xi) = \sum_n \langle f, W_n\rangle W_n(\xi)$ will always make sense in an $L^2$ sense if the $\{ W_n \}$ is an orthonormal basis. After that, if you perform calculations without regard to precise rigor, you arrive at $f(\xi) = \int f(\xi')\sum_n W_n(\xi')^*W_n(\xi) d\xi'$, which motives writing $\sum_n W_n(\xi')^*W_n(\xi) = \delta(\xi'-\xi)$.

Comment: But that relation is a necessary and sufficient or only sufficient condition for completeness?

Comment: When dealing with $\sum_n W_n(\xi)^*W_n(x) = \delta(\xi-x)$ as a symbolic relation that has meaning only in the context of integrals, then the condition is essentially necessary and sufficient. Though I would argue you need the extra outside integral for the inner product in order to be perfectly precise. And that leads to $\langle f,g\rangle = \sum_n \langle f,w_n\rangle \langle w_n,g\rangle$ for all $f,g$, which is a known equivalent of completeness for the orthonormal set $\{ w_n \}$. Typically I'm not bothered by such use of $\delta$, because it tends to be used correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your second question answers your first question. As this is coming from a physics class I am going to blithely ignore all issues of convergence, etc. Once we have

$$a_n = \int f(\xi) W_n^{\ast}(\xi) \, d \xi$$

we get

$$f(\xi) = \sum \left( \int f(\xi') W_n^{\ast}(\xi') \, d \xi' \right) W_n(\xi) = \int f(\xi') \sum W_n^{\ast}(\xi') W_n(\xi) \, d \xi'.$$

On the other hand, we also have

$$f(\xi) = \int f(\xi') \delta(\xi' - \xi) \, d \xi'.$$

It is perhaps easier to first understand the analogous finite-dimensional statement, which becomes a statement about how to write the identity matrix in terms of an orthonormal basis of a finite-dimensional Hilbert space.